# UIPickerView does not show added subview in UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uipickerview

at the end of that example I'm adding subviews to the UIView, but the subs arent showing. The UIView is showing (made it for test blue and it was there) If I return rowLabel or rowImage seperatly they are showing. but not embedded in the UIView. Any Ideas?

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    NSDictionary *oneResultDict = [_postArray objectAtIndex:row];

    NSData *tmpImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[oneResultDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]]];

    UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithData:tmpImageData];

    UIImageView *rowImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tmpImage];
    rowImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60);

    UILabel *rowLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 200, 60)];
    rowLabel.text = [oneResultDict objectForKey:@"title"];

    UIView *rowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 160)];

    [rowView insertSubview:rowImage atIndex:0];
    [rowView insertSubview:rowLabel atIndex:1];

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: solved. The "*rowView" was set to Y-height 160. that was somehow to big. when I lowered it to 80 all was at the right place. Now I need to find out why that happens. What is the rule behind it?

Comment: The `UIView` that show the returned view from your method might *clip* your view, try setting `clipsToBounds` flag to `NO`. - It won't give you the full solution I assume, but it might help you with debugging the issue.

Comment: It was really the y-height. IF I put all y-heights... rowLabel, rowImage and rowView to the same size of 60. all is working fine. clipsToBound didnt work as well. has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

you just to have to return your view, you don't need to do [rowView insertSubview:rowImage atIndex:0]. It is better to do like

(if component == 0)
     [rowView addsubview:rowImage]

(if component == 1)
     [rowView addsubview:rowLabel]

return rowView

Answer (score -1):

From `insertSubview:atIndex:` Apple Docs:

> The index in the array of the subviews property at which to insert the
>   view.  Subview indices start at 0 and cannot be greater than the
>   number of subviews.

In other words: You don't have any subviews yet, so yo can't `insert` a new subview.
Try using `addSubview:` instead:

```
[rowView addSubview:rowImage];
[rowView addSubview:rowLabel];
```

Comment: nope, that wasnt the problem. see my comment. it was the size of the *rowView Y-height